# Broken pipe exceptions from Redis client Jedis

Tags: scala, playframework, redis, akka, jedis

We have a redis client calls from a play framework Application. This Redis calls are being made from an Actor using Akka Schedular. This scheduler runs every 60 secs which makes redis calls along with other JDBC calls. After scheduler has run for a few mins we start seeing following into the log files and app stops responding to any Redis client calls. This is my first encounter with Redis so any pointers, help is appreciated.

```
redis.host = localhost

redis.port = 6379

redis.timeout = 10

redis.pool.maxActive =110

redis.pool.maxIdle = 50

redis.pool.maxWait = 3000

redis.pool.testOnBorrow = true

redis.pool.testOnReturn = true

redis.pool.testWhileIdle = true

redis.pool.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 60000

redis.pool.numTestsPerEvictionRun = 10

Exception details:

redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.flush(Connection.java:69) ~[redis.clients.jedis-2.3.0.jar:na]
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisPubSub.subscribe(JedisPubSub.java:58) ~[redis.clients.jedis-2.3.0.jar:na]
............    
at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:498) [com.typesafe.akka.akka-actor_2.10-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:456) [com.typesafe.akka.akka-actor_2.10-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:237) [com.typesafe.akka.akka-actor_2.10-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:219) [com.typesafe.akka.akka-actor_2.10-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:386) [com.typesafe.akka.akka-actor_2.10-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.3.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.3.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.3.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.3.jar:na]
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:113) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:159) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at redis.clients.util.RedisOutputStream.flushBuffer(RedisOutputStream.java:31) ~[redis.clients.jedis-2.3.0.jar:na]
    at redis.clients.util.RedisOutputStream.flush(RedisOutputStream.java:223) ~[redis.clients.jedis-2.3.0.jar:na]
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.flush(Connection.java:67) ~[redis.clients.jedis-2.3.0.jar:na]
    ... 15 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the time out and that the client you used to do the subscribe timed out / got DC ed.

Comment: well, timeout setting was 0 before. Doesn't 0 setting mean never time out? I thought errors were due to 0 timeout setting which we have changed to 10 secs (both on redis client config file and redis server) but these errors are persistent and brings server to halt.

Comment: Jedis takes timeouts as milliseconds and not seconds so you might need to change that.

Comment: This doc says timeout is in sec : http://download.redis.io/redis-stable/redis.conf . not true?

Comment: thats the timeout u set through redis.conf , it is indeed in seconds. But on the contrary ur Jedis constructor should take milliseconds so put in new Jedis("localhost",6379,10000) for 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently encountered a similar problem with Redis and the problem was, I was not returning the Jedis resource after subscribing so the connections were leaking, and the app was not responding after couple of connections. So don't forget to return jedis resource after whatever you do it:

```
Jedis j = play.Play.application().plugin(RedisPlugin.class).jedisPool().getResource();
j.subscribe(listener, redisChannel);
play.Play.application().plugin(RedisPlugin.class).jedisPool().returnResource(j);
```